# How to create a new character device under /proc/device file?

Tags: io, serial-port, character-device

I am trying to create a node with `mknod /tmp/ttyACM0 c 166 0` command but then `No such device or address` error returns when I try to open serial port with ttyACM0 because there is no device in proc/device file that name is ttyACM and id is 166. How can I create a new device in the devices file?

EDIT:

I don't see any module that name is cdc_acm on my system(Under /lib/modules)
Also, my system recognizes my device.

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0658:0200
```

Comment: do you have the `cdc_acm` module on your system (`lsmod | grep cdc_acm; find /lib/modules -name cdc-acm.ko`) ? does it recognize your device? what are the vendor and product id of your device? if you know them, `lsusb -dv 0e8d:0003` (of course, replace those numbers with your `vendor:product` ;-)). Please edit all that info into your question, don't reply in comments.

Comment: So then I see there is a missing module problem on my system, isn't there?

Comment: 1. the name of the file is cdc-acm.ko (with a dash, different from the module name which has an underscore -- `cdc_acm`). 2. the lsusb line doesn't mean that the your system recognizes your device; in order to have it work, a driver should attach to it -- this could be forced with an `alias` line in an `/etc/modprobe.d/*` file, **if** you know that that device implements the cdc acm spec (without having to be switched to with some commands) -- which is hard to tell based on the info you submitted.

Comment: I have actually run ' find / -name "*acm*" ' command on my system and there is no file that contains 'acm' key on my system. Also, I think it should be a standard process to add a character device on the device file. I have just asked about it. If I will be able to add a device that's id is 166 in the device file then my problem will be fixed.

Comment: As I told you, you can add an alias line, eg. `alias usb:v0658p0200d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* cdc_acm` to `/etc/modprobe.d/foo.conf`. But if the driver does not support your device, or if the device needs to be sent some commands to switch mode, IT WILL NOT WORK. There's no magic. And your device could have been already claimed by another driver, or the cdc_acm module may have been built-in. Good luck, anyway!